# How do I pass in generic parameters to a method in java?

Tags: java, rest, generics, java-8

I wish to let the `withParameters(String token, RiskRating details)` method take in an object of type that's either a RiskRating object or is a subclass of it

Something like `withParameters(String token, T extends RiskRating details)`

```
public Response withParameters(String token, RiskRating details)  {
        return SerenityRest.given()
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Token " + token)
                .body(details)
                .post(WebServiceEndPoints.RISKRATING.getUrl());

    }
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `T extends RiskRating` is already correct, you just need to place it correctly. See the given link how to do so for methods.

Comment: `public  <T extends RiskRating> Response withParameters(String token, T details) {}`

Comment: Your method does already “take in an object of type that's either a RiskRating object or is a subclass of it”.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for generics here.

Passing an instance of a subclass to a method which takes a parent class is fine.

A subclass IS-A superclass.

```
public class Animal {}
class SubAnimal extends Animal {}

class Example {
    static void takesAnimal(Animal a) {}
    static void passesSubAnimal() {
        takesAnimal(new SubAnimal());
    }
}
```